# I need slot type of intent for my Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am creating a skill but I need a slot type for my intent (which takes a complete sentence as input) but it should be in Indian.

Like: `AMAZON.LITERAL`

It only supports English(U.K) and English(US).

I need any slot type which takes a complete sentence as input but supports English(Indian). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also seraching for this one for last 2 weeks. And also i email to support team of alexa. After that i got confirmation from support team  that AMAZON.LITERAL slot type is not support feature in english(india).

Comment: what alternate you used?

Comment: I created a skill in english(us).

Answer (score 0):

You can only fake it:

- create your own slot type
- for this slot type give a lot of different utterances in different length (like "one", "this is a sentence.." and so on)
- use your slot with custom slot type in your utterances

I also needed it for a simple echo skill in GERMAN which just reply.
See the dialogue model here:

- https://gitlab.com/timguy/alexa-wiederhall/blob/master/src/main/java/github/timguy/wiederhall/speechAssets/IntentSchemaSlotsUtterances_SkillBuilder.json
- instead of samples `"{slotOne}"` you could use `" save the text I say {slotOne}"`

**UPDATE**

I didn't tried it but just read it now. Now you could use `AMAZON.SearchQuery`
https://developer.amazon.com/de/blogs/alexa/post/a2716002-0f50-4587-b038-31ce631c0c07/enhance-speech-recognition-of-your-alexa-skills-with-phrase-slots-and-amazon-searchquery

Answer (score 0):

*Amazon.Literal* is deprecated and if you are changing the skill to en-Us then it won't be available in any other locale which i think you never want.
Moreover as per my interaction with amazon development team it is not a good option to have a free text in terms of *Amazon.Literal* as it would  add more **ambiguity** in their NLP for resolving intent and slot than addressing the underlying issue. Since Alexa doesn't provide you any confidence factor in intent/slot then it would be a big problem to your skill as any random word/sentence would match to *Amazon.Literal*.
It's always good to restrict your user input as you are developing the skill especially when it involves AI/NLP.

***Update***

> You can use the new slot type ***[Amazon.SearchQuery](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/a2716002-0f50-4587-b038-31ce631c0c07/enhance-speech-recognition-of-your-alexa-skills-with-phrase-slots-and-amazon-searchquery)*** that would suit your problem