# Develop alexa skills without intents

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I want to develop my own logic for intents and the stuff so I want alexa sends me all the phrase without slots etc... This is because I will send it to my server using an API.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
But results are probably worse because you would use Alexa only as an speech to text engine without finding the right intents and filling the slots.

You can create a slot to catch all.

- See an old answer by me here:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48686043/3276902
- Or from another user here:
  [Alexa - catchall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948118/alexa-catchall)

Than in you backend handle the intent by calling / using your backend logic to process the text.

Just out of curiositiy: You think you could handle the intents better or you just already have a model to process text?

Comment: Because my backend is chatgpt.

Comment: Btw the second answer is really cool. I was using the search slot type. But with the person slot type I don't need to prefix the intent with a word.

Comment: Cool about chatgpt. Let me know when Skill is certified or invite me as beta tester. Already wanted to search for skill like that.
Also thought about it for german skills but couldn't find free REST API endpoints. You build up your endpoints or using exisitng ones?

Comment: unfortunately I think the project has to stop because of the 8 seconds hard limit alexa imposes for runtime, which is far less than time required for chatgpt. The feature "skill resumption" could have resolved it, but after they announced it in 2021 they still didn't implement it.

Comment: you could work around it by sending a notification to the user when backend is done. It's not a dialogue but I woul use it anyway: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/proactive-events-api.html